# Bullet points aren't being recognized when reading PDF

Tags: itext7

I am reading a PDF using iText7 for C# and it doesn't seem to be identifying bullet points properly (either not displayed at all or as '?). This is the code I am using:

```cs
static string ReadPdf(string fileName)
{
    PdfReader pdfRead = new PdfReader(fileName);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfRead);

    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

    StringBuilder processed = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
        string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
        processed.Append(text);
    }

    return processed.ToString();
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: The code is completely fine, it is possible that the pdf might not have bullet point character. Try reading a pdf with different font

Comment: Also bullet points sometimes are not generated using text drawing instructions but using vector graphics instructions. In such a case text extraction won't see them.